# How to refer to the previous calculated field in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set:

```
[0, 0.095, 0.104, 0.17, 0.189, 0.113, 0.198, 0.208, 0.274, 0.293, 0.312, 0.217, 0.208, 0.198, 0.17, 0.114, 0.095, 0.038]
```

I did some calculations in Excel like this:

[image]

I did the code in Python, but it does not work:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0.095, 0.104, 0.17, 0.189, 0.113, 0.198, 0.208, 0.274, 0.293, 0.312, 0.217, 0.208, 0.198, 0.17, 0.114, 0.095, 0.038]})

df['B'] = np.where((df['A'] - df['B'].shift(1)).abs() > 0.1, df['A'], df['B'].shift(1))

Result: KeyError: 'B'
```

How could I calculate the column 'B' in Python using Pandas without cycle?

Comment: You are calling column `B` while it does not exist yet

Comment: You are correct, but if I create column "B" beforehand (eg df ['B'] = 0) it doesn't solve the problem. Result: B = [NaN, 0.000, 0.104, 0.170, 0.189, 0.113, 0.198, 0.208, 0.274, 0.293, 0.312, 0.217, 0.208, 0.198, 0.170, 0.114 0.000 0.000]. Doesn't match the Excel example

Comment: I suspect it's impossible to do this without a loop, because of the way each value in the B column depends on the previous one. Excel may not show you a loop, but I'm pretty sure it uses one to calculate this.

Comment: Question is good but maybe such a large screenshot of excel is unnecessary. Just the function would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define custom function with `eps` argument as threshold value:

```
import pandas as pd

def fixed_change(s, eps):
    l = []
    tmp = s[0]
    for e in s:
        if abs(tmp-e) > eps:
            l.append(e)
            tmp = e
        else:
            l.append(tmp)
    return l
```

Then calculate column `B`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0.095, 0.104, 0.17, 0.189, 0.113, 0.198, 0.208, 0.274, 0.293, 0.312, 0.217, 0.208, 0.198, 0.17, 0.114, 0.095, 0.038]})
df['B'] = fixed_change(df['A'], 0.1)
```

result:

```
        A      B
0   0.000  0.000
1   0.095  0.000
2   0.104  0.104
3   0.170  0.104
4   0.189  0.104
5   0.113  0.104
6   0.198  0.104
7   0.208  0.208
8   0.274  0.208
9   0.293  0.208
10  0.312  0.312
11  0.217  0.312
12  0.208  0.208
13  0.198  0.208
14  0.170  0.208
15  0.114  0.208
16  0.095  0.095
17  0.038  0.095
```

Visual confirmation of result `df.plot()`:

[image]

Comment: I thought Pandas allows to solve that sort of problems without iterating. Anyway thank you. I tried 10m data set - speed is acceptable.

Comment: Seeking for buit-in pandas solution was my initial effort, but maybe I missed something or answer is not obvious. I'll be happy to see non iterative solution or some kind of vectorized code as well.